# Remove directory name from url Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, permalinks

I have a website on www.example.com. On that domain Wordpress website is in directory **wp**.

So to access my wordpress website you should go to www.example.com/wp and that is the main website.

In root i have index.html where you choose language and then go to Wordpress website

What i need sounds simple! :) I want to remove **wp** from url using .htaccess or whatever else could do the trick, so when browse Wordpress website it shouild work without **wp**!

I must note that website must stay in wp folder!

Is this achievable?

Comment: Visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory and see instructions under `Using a pre-existing subdirectory install`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) in your dashboard, go to settings -> general and make sure

a) wordpress directory -> http://mydomain.com/wp

b) site address -> http://mydomain.com

2) move your index.php from subdirectory to the root (MOVE, don't just copy)

3) edit your index.php to read

```
    /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require('./wp/wp-blog-header.php');
```

where "wp" is your subdirectory

4) delete any .htaccess file in the subdirectory

5) add this to your .htaccess in the root

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Under this setup, your wordpress installation will be located in /wp/ directory. Visitors will visit your site using http://mydomain.com.

If you want to have a good read-up on everything so you know exactly what you're doing, read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 2):

Add (or edit) the .htaccess file and put this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This basically creates a rewrite rule for your apache server and all traffic is redirected according the `RewriteBase` directive.

Comment: Where should i put this htaccess file? Inside root folder or inside wp folder?

Comment: The file should be called ".htaccess", mark the dot at the beginning. It should be placed on root of your web server, i.e. on www.example.com