# Deleting "wordpress" from URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I just launched my first WordPress blog, and I went into Settings > Permalinks to make the links look like this:

mysite.com/wordpress/a-fun-day

I just wondered if there's a way to either delete "wordpress" from the URL, so it looks like this...

mysite.com/a-fun-day

...or replace "wordpress" with a category, like this:

mysite.com/events/a-fun-day
mysite.com/world/japan

Comment: Deleting wordpress is easy - and fun, too. Step 1: remove all traces of it from your computer. You're done! No more steps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove directory name from url Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516600/remove-directory-name-from-url-wordpress)

Comment: Yes, that link looks like the ticket. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you uploaded all "Wordpress" folder to your Public_html. That's reason you always get /wordpress/ in your links !

Now How to delete "wordpress" from the URL ? Please try:

**step 1:** Goto your folder "Public_html/Wordpress/"

**step 2:** Select all files and folders, Copy all to "Public_html" folder

**step 3:** Goto your wordpress admin panel and Goto config option

**step 4:** Change link live site to your domain (if it display wrong).

If you still have errors, you can Install wordpress again but you need upload all files and folders inside "wordpress" folder to "public_html"

Comment: This is the correct answer, but step 3 should be done first. Why? Because you won't be able to get into your admin panel after doing step 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your apache configuration, you can change your document root to include /wordpress, and change your Wordpress site to exclude /wordpress.